# simple verification game theoretic solution concept

Tags: real-numbers, game-theory

I have a problem with verification of a simple consistency problem in the sinppet below. Namely I do not know what should I check in the table in the second snippet
for the claim in the first snippet that the table is $CG-$consistent.
The verification can be left to me but I need a hint **what equations** should I verify
for $E=200$ and $E=300$,say.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT** The following should be used in reply to my question:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Consult the book of Theo Driessen, (1988, Chap VI), Cooperative Games, Solutions, and Applications, Kluwer Academic Publishers, which should give you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt I'm looking at page 153 in that book, but I do not know what numbers should I assing to $d_1$ and $d_2$ so that they are in accordance with table I in the snippet.See my **EDIT**.

Comment: I would try the claims $d_{1}=100,d_{2}=200$ in connection with the estates $E=100,200,300$ as given by the mentioned book on page 152.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt I'm reading that nice book you have referred to me. I would like to know what is $d(N)$ on the page 155. I know, however, what is $d_n$.

Comment: If you have $n$-agents, then $d_{n}$ indicates the claim of the last agent $n$, whereas $d(N)$ is the sum of the total claims,  which is defined by $d(N):=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\,d_{i}$.